# Altering legend labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, legend, matplotlib

I have a choropleth map which displays crime percentage change. It is plotted from a geodataframe and the choropleth intervals are determined in the background by Python.

Unfortunately, the first label in the legend (for white polygons) shows "0.00 - -50.00" when it is in actual fact starting from -286, not 0. Similarly, the last label shows "30.18 - nan".

How do I change these to "Less than -50.0" and "Greater than 30.18"?

[image: Percentage Change Map]

Please see my code below:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(16, 16))

PoliceDataMap.plot(column='PercChange', scheme='quantile', k=5, legend=True, axes=ax, colormap='Reds', linewidth=0.2, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_axis_off()

ax.set_title("Crime Percentage Change between Jan 2011 & Jan 2015", **TitleFont)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify items of the legend manually:

```
new_labels=[
            '<50',
            '-50 - -27.48',
            '-27348 - -4.75',
            '-4.76 - 30.18',
            '>30.18'
]

leg = ax.get_legend()
for text, label in zip(leg.get_texts(), new_labels):
    text.set_text(label)
```